# Evaluate $\int_{0}^\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx $$

My question for this is can I take out the square root so it would be

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_{0}^\frac{1}{2}{\sin^{-1}x} \,dx $$

So all i have to do is find the anti-derivative  of $\sin^{-1}x$ then multiply the $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ back in afterwards? Is there a simpler way?

Comment: You can only take out constant factors from integrals. Otherwise you'd get silly stuff like $$\int_0^1 x\, dx = x\int_0^1 1\, dx = x \cdot 1 = x$$ which is certainly wrong because definite integrals are constant!

Comment: got it thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** let $u = \arcsin x$. Then $du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$. You're not allowed to move the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ term out in front since it has an $x$ in it and the variable of integration is $x$--so the integral depends on that term too!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the fact that $\arcsin'x=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ .

Answer (score -1):

I may suggest that this integral must be like this Integral arc sin x d(arc sin x) from 0 to 1/2. thus the answer must be π^2/72

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: This has already been (at least as well) explained more than one year ago.